# Can we do pagination inside a custom component in hybris?

Tags: ajax, pagination, components, sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

Can we do pagination inside a custom component in hybris?
We have a requirement wherein the pagination needs to be done inside a custom component.
Is there any way through which we can achieve it..

Answer (score 0):

Owl carousel comes packaged with the Hybris accelerator frontend. It's quite easy to use - take a look at the demos below and see if it suits your requirements.

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html